# Making python interpret spaces as newline characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure about input format that user will enter. There are two possibities:

code:

```
n=int(input("enter the no of workers \n"))
print("enter the names of workers")
NameList=[]
for i in range(n):
    NameList.append(input())
print(NameList)
```

possibility 1:

enter the no of workers

4

enter the names of workers

name1

name2

name3

name4

['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']

working great...!!

possibility 2:

input will be :

enter the no of workers

4

enter the names of workers

name1 name2 name3 name4

in this case my code will fail. I'll need to write different code( i know how to write that ;) ) to accept this format of input.

So is there anyway that one code will work for both input formats. By treating spaces as Enter. Thanks

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in the title.

Comment: Can a worker name include a space?

Comment: no DeepSpace. There will be no space in worker name.

Comment: raw_input requires a newline, but you can use split() on that line to separate the names.

Comment: edit: oops nevermind additional comment here.  Do use the split comment, though.

Comment: @KennyOstrom OP is using Python 3. There is no `raw_input`, and `input` behaves as `raw_input` did in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a worker name can't include a space, you can check that and change the behavior accordingly.

This will even work if the user combine the 2 options (e.g. entering `'a'` and then `'b c'`), although it is not perfect (it is possible to get more than `n` names, for example if `n == 3` and inputting `'a b'` and `'c d'`)

```
n = int(input("enter the no of workers \n"))
print("enter the names of workers")
NameList = []
while len(NameList) < n:
    worker_name = input()
    if ' ' in worker_name:
        if NameList:
            NameList.extend(worker_name.split())
        else:
            NameList = worker_name.split()
    else:
        NameList.append(worker_name)
print(NameList)
```

Comment: no man! i can't tell user the input format. That input with spaces or without spaces. it's his/her choice.

Comment: wait. Let me check.

Comment: @SamarYadav See my (again) updated answer. It will work even if the user combines the 2 options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the spaces, I would *highly* recommend the following:

```
for i in range(n):
    NameList.append(input("What is the name of worker " + i +"?"))
```

If you *absolutely* need to accept spaces, 
use DeepSpace's answer.